# Arrays Dinámicos y Basura

Tags: c++, windows

El objetivo es que el programa muestre por pantalla la posible basura que ha podido dejar si no se utilizaran arrays dinámicos. Usamos al principio del código:

> _CrtSetDbgFlag ( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF );

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


using namespace std;

int Datos();
void rellenarDatos(int datos);
void mostrarDatos(int datos);
void liberarMemoria();

int *arreglo;

int main()
{
    _CrtSetDbgFlag ( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF );
    int datos;
    datos = Datos();
    rellenarDatos(datos);
    mostrarDatos(datos);
    liberarMemoria();
    getch();
    return 0;
}

int Datos()
{
    int notas;
    cout << "Introduzca el numero de notas: ";
    cin >> notas;

    return notas;
}

void rellenarDatos(int datos)
{
    arreglo = new int[datos];

    for(int i = 0; i < datos; i++)
    {
        cout << "Ingrese el valor " << (i+1) << ": ";
        cin >>arreglo[i];
    }
}

void mostrarDatos(int datos)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < datos; i++)
    {
        cout << "Nota " << (i+1) << ":" << arreglo[i] << endl;
        cout << "Direccion: " << &arreglo[i] << endl << endl;
    }
}

void liberarMemoria()
{
    delete[] arreglo;
}
```

¿Cómo muestro por pantalla la posible basura? La IDE usada es Visual Studio. Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ¿Cómo muestro por pantalla la posible basura?

Tú no la muestras, lo hace el propio programa (en la consola de Visual Studio al finalizar). Según [la documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/crtsetdbgflag):

> La función **_CrtSetDbgFlag** permite a la aplicación controlar cómo el gestor de memoria heap de depuración rastrea los alojamientos de memoria [...], la aplicación puede ordenar al gestor de memoria heap de depuración que haga operaciones especiales de depuración, que incluyen verificar fugas de memoria e informar si se encuentra alguna.

Así que, provoca deliberadamente alguna fuga de memoria y al finalizar el programa comprueba el contenido de la ventana de Output/Salida de Visual Studio.